# Syntax Change in lua 5.2 C api

Tags: c, lua

I was trying to compile the example provided in the book [Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/24.1.html)

But only works for lua 5.1, **What are the steps to do it on 5.2?**

This is the code I am using

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <lualib.h>

int main (void) {
  char buff[256];
  int error;
  lua_State *L = lua_open();   /* opens Lua */
  luaL_openlibs(L);  
  while (fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), stdin) != NULL) {
    error = luaL_loadbuffer(L, buff, strlen(buff), "line") ||
      lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);
    if (error) {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s", lua_tostring(L, -1));
      lua_pop(L, 1);  /* pop error message from the stack */
    }
  }
  lua_close(L);
  return 0;
}
```

After compiling with `gcc test01.c -I/usr/include/lua5.2 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -llua5.2` I get the following errors:

```
test01.c: In function ‘main’:
test01.c:10:18: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cas
t [enabled by default]                                                         
   lua_State *L = lua_open();   /* opens Lua */
                  ^
/tmp/ccyPRlV3.o: In function `main':
test01.c:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `lua_open'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Apparently the `lua_open` call was removed already in version 5.1. See e.g. [the "Incompatibilities with the Previous Version" section of the 5.1 reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#7).

Comment: In Lua 5.2.2 they use lua_State *L = lua_newstate();

Comment: @BajMile luaL_newstate; see why it's important for interfaces to be immutable? There should be a compatibility API out of the box.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`luaopen()` is not used anymore, it's replaced by `luaL_newstate`, you can use [`luaL_newstate`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#luaL_newstate) to create a state with a standard allocation function:

```
lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();    /* opens Lua */
luaL_openlibs(L);                  /* opens the standard libraries */
```

This API is changed [since Lua 5.1](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#7.3)

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it when I upgrade to 5.2.3